# I want to find QID BASED ON SPECIFICATION WHEN i INPUT UID = 1

Tags: mysql

```
tbl1

+----+--------------------------+
|UID |  SPECIFICATION           |
+----+--------------------------+
| 1  |  1                       |
+----+--------------------------+
| 1  |  2                       |
+----+--------------------------+
| 1  |  3                       |
+----+--------------------------+

tbl2

+----+--------------------------+
|QID |  SPECIFICATION           |
+----+--------------------------+
| 1  |  1,2                     |
+----+--------------------------+
| 2  |  2,3                     |
+----+--------------------------+
| 3  |  3,1                     |
+----+--------------------------+
```

I want to find QID BASED ON SPECIFICATION

WHEN i INPUT UID = 1

Comment: So UID 1 should return QID 1 and 3, right?

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: no return qid = 1,2,3   @shmosel